# Splitting value of a varchar column into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

If I have a column in which strings vary in length but they ALL have a slash `\` within,
how can I SELECT to have one column display everything BEFORE the `\` and another column displaying everything AFTER the `\`?

```
name         column1     column2
DB5697\DEV   DB5697      DEV
```

I have seen `CHARINDEX` and `REVERSE` on MSDN but haven't been able to put together a soltuion.

How can I best split a varchar/string column value into 2 columns in a result set in TSQL ?

Comment: If at all possible once you figure out how to do this keep them separated. You are storing two values in a single column which is in violation of 1NF.

Comment: Your data has DB5697\DEV. Each of those pieces is obviously a different datapoint, which is why you are trying to separate them. One of the rules for first normal form is that every row and column intersection contains 1 and only 1 value. You should modify your data structure so that you can hold each value in their own column instead of cramming two pieces of data into a single column.

Comment: I dont have access to do that unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/851ac/1/0)):

```
SELECT m.name,
       LEFT(m.name, CHARINDEX('\', m.name) - 1) AS column1,
       RIGHT(m.name, LEN(m.name) - CHARINDEX('\', m.name)) AS column2
FROM MyTable m
```

How to handle strings with no `\` in them ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9ebe/6/0)):

```
SELECT m.name,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\', m.name) = 0 THEN ''
            ELSE LEFT(m.name, CHARINDEX('\', m.name) - 1) END AS column1,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\', m.name) = 0 THEN '' 
            ELSE RIGHT(m.name, LEN(m.name) - CHARINDEX('\', m.name)) END AS column2
FROM MyTable m;
```

Comment: **@choloboy**, I edited my answer.  It should have been `m.name`.

Comment: i got this error: "Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: **@choloboy**, I added an SQL Fiddle example to show that it indeed works.

Comment: Linger, he likely has a row with \ at index 1, so your left getting a 0... case it out, `CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('\',COL)<=1 THEN '' ELSE ... END`.. you could also case the RIGHT() so if it's in the last index position it won't try a right().

Comment: @Linger what if there is a field thats longer? Example, 'DBA007\TOOl'

Comment: **@JiggsJedi**, I updated my SQL Fiddle to show that it does not matter if `\\` is the first character.

Comment: **@choloboy**,  My updated SQL Fiddle shows many examples of different length strings.  The length does not matter.  It handles them all properly.

Comment: Ahh... so he must have a row with no \ in it... which is not what he said.

Comment: @JiggsJedi, yes if there is no \ at all in the string then you will get the error.

Comment: I added an SQL Fiddle example showing how to handle a case where there is no \ in the string.

Answer (score 4):

what about using [PARSENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188006(v=sql.110).aspx) function in a tricky way?

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE #names 
(
      id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , name varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO #names (id, name)
VALUES 
    (1, 'DB5697\DEV'),
    (2, 'DB5800\STG'),
    (3, 'DB5900\PRD');
GO

SELECT
      name
    , PARSENAME(REPLACE(name, '\', '.'), 2) AS [Server]
    , PARSENAME(REPLACE(name, '\', '.'), 1) AS [Instance]
FROM
    #names;
GO

DROP TABLE #names;
GO
```

The [PARSENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188006(v=sql.110).aspx) function accepts 2 parameters and gets the name part of a fully qualified name. The second parameter is the part name enumerator.

Value 2 is for SCHEMA and 1 is for OBJECT.

So, with the [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862(v=sql.110).aspx) function the "\" char is replaced by "." in order to have a SCHEMA.OBJECT format of your SERVERNAME\INSTANCE values. Then, PARSENAME behave like having a simple object name in the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CHARINDEX to check for the character position of the splitter ('/') and use SUBSTRING to split the string. 
However care has to be taken to ensure you handle records without splitters else you would invoke an error. 
Also in the case where splitter is unavailable, decision has to be made as to which column the data should be mapped to. Here I am mapping data to FirstName and assigning NULL to LastName

```
DECLARE @TableBuyer TABLE (ID INT, FullName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TableBuyer
SELECT '1','Bryan/Greenberg' UNION ALL
SELECT '2','Channing/Tatum' UNION ALL
SELECT '3','Paul/William' UNION ALL
SELECT '4','EricBana' UNION ALL
SELECT '5','James/Lafferty' UNION ALL
SELECT '6','Wentworth/Miller'

SELECT
       CASE
       WHEN CHARINDEX('/', FullName) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, CHARINDEX('/', FullName) - 1)
       ELSE FullName
       END AS FirstName
       ,
       CASE
       WHEN CHARINDEX('/', FullName) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX('/', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName))
       ELSE NULL
       END AS LastName
FROM @TableBuyer;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @TableBuyer TABLE (ID INT, FullName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TableBuyer
SELECT '1','Bryan/Greenberg' UNION ALL
SELECT '2','Channing/Tatum' UNION ALL
SELECT '3','Paul/William' UNION ALL
SELECT '4','EricBana' UNION ALL
SELECT '5','James/Lafferty' UNION ALL
SELECT '6','Wentworth/Miller'


select left(FullName, len(FullName)-CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(FullName))) as firstname,
substring(FullName, len(FullName)-CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(FullName))+ 2, len(FullName)) as lastname
from @TableBuyer
```

OR

```
select left(FullName, len(FullName)-CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(FullName))) as firstname,
RIGHT(FullName, len(FullName)-CHARINDEX('/', FullName)) as lastname
from @TableBuyer
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no "simple" method.  Something like this should work:

```
select left(col, charindex('\', col) - 1) as column1,
       right(col, charindex('\', reverse(col)) - 1) as column2
```

You might need to double up on the backslash (`'\\'`) to get it to work properly.