# How to Split Varchar into 2 Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following variable:

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(8000);
SET @FileName = '1351231_a2s1.jpg|65413213_fddf.png'
```

I want to split this into 2 columns:

```
Imag1                     Image2
---------------------------------
 1351231_a2s1.jpg         65413213_fddf.png'
```

Comment: And you've tried what? Where are you stuck? You might want to start with the [MSDN documentation on T-SQL string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting value of a varchar column into two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828567/splitting-value-of-a-varchar-column-into-two-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that you have `|` as your delimiter.

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(@FileName,CHARINDEX('|',@FileName)-1) as Image1,
    SUBSTRING(@FileName,CHARINDEX('|',@FileName) + 1, LEN(@FileName) - CHARINDEX('|',@FileName)+1) as Image2
```

Comment: What if there is no `|` delimiter in your string??